# How to use EJS in Node.js instead of JADE

Tags: linux, node.js, express

I'm trying to create a simple app with express but i want to use EJS instead of JADE. So I do the following:

- Step 1 npm install express generator -g
- Step 2 express myApp
- Step 3 cd myApp
- Step 4 npm install
- Step 5 npm install ejs
- Step 6 Replace app.set('view engine', 'jade'); with app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
- Step 7 run the Application using command set debug=myApp:* & npm start

But when i'm trying to see my web Page through localhost:3000 it shows me an error.

```
Error: Failed to lookup view "error" in views directory "E:\Express\myApp\views"
   at EventEmitter.render (E:\Express\myApp\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:579:17)
   at ServerResponse.render (E:\Express\myApp\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:961:7)
   at E:\Express\myApp\app.js:53:7 
   at Layer.handle_error (E:\Express\myApp\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:71:5)
   at trim_prefix (E:\Express\myApp\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:310:13)
   at E:\Express\myApp\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:280:7
   at Function.process_params (E:\Express\myApp\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:330:12)
   at IncomingMessage.next (E:\Express\myApp\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:271:10)
   at done (E:\Express\myApp\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:956:25)
   at EventEmitter.render (E:\Express\myApp\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:581:14)
```

Please tell me why it's happening.

Answer (score 1):

You could have generated express project with ejs template using following command:

```
express myApp -e
```

In you case, you have created express project with jade template and trying to replace jade with ejs everywhere.

There errors you have mentioned are due to nonexistence of file `error.ejs` in path directory "`E:\Express\myApp\views`".
Please check the path directory "`E:\Express\myApp\views`" and rename `error.jade` to `error.ejs`.

If you face any issues, please post it here.

Answer (score 0):

As the express generator app will create initial layouts and views using Jade, the way to replace with EJS is creating new layouts and basics views on EJS.

The error message said it is unable to find the 'error' view to render. That could be that the file doesn't exist or because it is not a EJS file

**update:** The express generator command supports `--ejs` or `-e` flags to change the view engine when creating a new project

Comment: I feel this is probably a good answer but the English needs to be fixed.

Comment: Sorry excuse my bad english. Please feel free to suggest edit or point me to the mistake

Comment: Thank you guys (http://stackoverflow.com/users/162698/rob and http://stackoverflow.com/users/5212479/daniel-aristizabal) may be i asked stupid question but m very new for this and stuck every time in something...

Comment: Is ok, is not stupid. Let me know if solve your issue or give you more info about the problem.

Comment: yeah it resolved now :) http://stackoverflow.com/users/5212479/daniel-aristizabal i used express --ejs abd its working fine